# How to draw a multi-line chart with d3 version7 graph with string in x-axis?

Tags: d3.js

I am a working on multiline chart using d3 version7 , I have data like

```
data1: sample1[] = [
{
symbol: 'a',
x1: '2022-01-01',
y1: 150
},
{
symbol: 'c',
x1: '2022-01-01',
y1: 300
},
{
symbol: 'a',
x1: '2022-01-02',
y1: 200
},
{
symbol: 'c',
x1: '2022-01-02',
y1: 700
},
{
symbol: 'a',
x1: '2022-01-03',
y1: 750
},
{
symbol: 'c',
x1: '2022-01-03',
y1: 100
},
];
```

In X-axis I want to display x1 as string and group with a symbol.
I am able to plot x-axis and y-axis from below code

```
const x = d3.scaleBand()
      .domain(this.data1.map((d: any) => { return d.x1 }))
      .range([0, this.width]);
    this.svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${this.height})`)
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(5));
    // Add Y axis
    const y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(this.data1, ((d: any) => {
        return d.y1;[![enter image description here][1]][1]
      }))])
      .range([this.height, 0]);
    this.svg.append("g")
      .call(
        d3.axisLeft(y)
      );
```

And It looks like this [screenshot of axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYzfX.png)

Now When draw a multiple line using this code

```
const dataNest = Array.from(
      d3.group(this.data1, d => d.symbol), ([key, value]) => ({ key, value })
    );
    var legendSpace = this.width / dataNest.length; // spacing for the legend
    dataNest.forEach((d1: any, i: any) => {
      const xScale = d3
        .scaleBand()
        .domain(d1.value.map((d: any) => {  return d.x1 }))
        // .domain([0, d3.max(this.data1.map((d: any) => d.x1))])
        .range([0, this.width])
      // y-scale
      const yScale = d3
        .scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(this.data1.map((d: any) => d.y1))])
        .range([this.height, 0]);
      // Data line
      const line = d3
        .line()
        .x((d: any) => d.x1)
        .y((d: any) => yScale(d.y1));
      this.svg.append("path")
        .data(dataNest)
        .join("path")
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .style("stroke", this.colors[i])
        .attr("d", line(d1.value));
      // Add the Legend
      this.svg.append("text")
        .attr("x", (legendSpace / 2) + i * legendSpace)  // space legend
        .attr("y", this.height + (this.margin.bottom / 2) + 15)
        .attr("class", "legend")    // style the legend
        .style("fill", this.colors[i])
        .text(d1.key);
    });
```

I am not able to plot any line and I am getting an error saying,
**Error:  attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,160LNaN,146.…".**
So anyone have solution for displaying the multiline chart.

Answer (score 1):

In your line generator function, you don't use the `xScale` to convert values to pixels.

```
  const line = d3
    .line()
    .x((d: any) => d.x1)
    .y((d: any) => yScale(d.y1));
```

should be

```
  const line = d3
    .line()
    .x((d: any) => xScale(d.x1))
    .y((d: any) => yScale(d.y1));
```

A few additional notes:

- In every loop of the `forEach` you define a new `xScale` and `yScale` that are identical to the existing `x` and `y` used for rendering the axes. Just use `x` and `y`.
- The same goes for the `line` generator, which should be the same for all lines.
- Why do you use a `forEach` on the `dataNest` array? This is what the d3 data join is for as worked out in the snippet below.
- Use an appropriate scale for the data type. `scaleBand` is for categorical data and something like bar charts. You have dates and should use `scaleTime`. If you really don't want to use a time scale, stick to `scalePoint` for line charts as the bandwidth is fixed to zero.

```js
const data1 = [
{symbol: 'a', x1: '2022-01-01', y1: 150},
{symbol: 'c', x1: '2022-01-01', y1: 300},
{symbol: 'a', x1: '2022-01-02', y1: 200},
{symbol: 'c', x1: '2022-01-02', y1: 700},
{symbol: 'a', x1: '2022-01-03', y1: 750},
{symbol: 'c', x1: '2022-01-03', y1: 100},
];

const width = 500,
      height = 180;

const svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

const x = d3.scalePoint()
  .domain(data1.map(d => d.x1))
  .range([30, width-30]);
svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${height-30})`)
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(5));
const y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data1, d => d.y1)])
  .range([height-30, 0]);
svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(30, 0)`)
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
    
const dataNest = Array.from(
  d3.group(data1, d => d.symbol), ([key, value]) => ({ key, value })
);
const line = d3.line()
  .x(d => x(d.x1))
  .y(d => y(d.y1));
svg.selectAll("path.line")
  .data(dataNest)
  .join("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .style("stroke", d => d.key === 'a' ? 'blue' : 'red')
    .attr("d", d => line(d.value));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.3.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried like this , I have created line object as well as the line generator
`const line = d3
.line()
.x((d: any) => (d.x1))
.y((d: any) => (d.y1));
this.svg.selectAll("path.line")
.data(dataNest)
.join("path")
.attr("class", "line")
.attr("fill", "none")
.style("stroke", d => d.key === 'a' ? 'blue' : 'red')
.attr("d", d => line(d.value));`
But, after doing this i am getting error under line(d.value) saying "No overload matches this call"

Comment: Why don't you apply the scales in the line generator?

Comment: I tried that way but I am getting this error

"Given a value in the input domain, returns the corresponding point derived from the output range. If the given value is not in the scale’s domain, returns undefined."

Comment: This is probably related to working in Typescript. The `scalePoint` returns undefined,, when the value is not in the domain, see [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/d51b8a80854a026aa559e32fdc235ed1676efd93/types/d3-scale/index.d.ts#L2552). Don't know how to resolve this...